# I have a Dropdownlist that have event sets values to the dropdownlist how can I use it in another class file?

Tags: asp.net, class, events, webforms

I have a dropdownlist in my aspx that have an event that sets values to it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("No Image News");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Small News");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Medium News");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Large News");
    DropDownList1.DataBind();         
}
```

I have a class file that have a method and I would like to use the dropdownlist inside of the method.

example: If selected dropdownlist value is "Car" do that..

Is it possible to somehow use the dropdownlist from the aspx file inside a class file?

Comment: You could extend the DropDownList class to include your method or pass a reference to the DropDownListinto your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function which take `DropDownList` as an argument
Call that function from you `.aspx.cs` file.
It will work.

Function will be like this

```
 public void MyControlData(DropDownList ddl)
 {

 }
```

Add reference of `System.Web` in you `.cs` file where you want to define this function.

### Edit 1

```
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; 


 public class MyControlData
 {

       public void MyControlData(DropDownList ddl)
       {
          // DO SOMETHING HERE
       }
  }
```